# Which linear maps $\mathbb{R}^{n^2} \to \mathbb{R}^{n^2} $ map $\text{GL}_n$ into $\text{GL}_n$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, lie-groups, matrix-calculus, general-linear-group

Can we characterize all **linear** maps $\mathbb{R}^{n^2} \to \mathbb{R}^{n^2} $ which map $\text{GL}_n$ into $\text{GL}_n$?

In particular, is it true that every such map is given by

$X \to AXB$ or $X \to AX^TB$ where $A,B \in \text{GL}_n$ and $X^T$ denotes the usual transpose operation on matrices.

(Note that changing the metric which respect to we are transposing amounts to changing $A,B$).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A theorem of Dieudonné [1] states the following:

> Let $F$ be a field and $f: M_n(F) \rightarrow M_n(F)$ be a bijective linear map such that $\det A = 0$ implies $\det f(A) = 0$. Then there exist $U, V \in \operatorname{GL}_n(F)$ such that either $f(X) = UXV$ for all $X \in M_n(F)$, or $f(X) = UX^TV$ for all $X \in M_n(F)$.

So assuming $f: M_n(F) \rightarrow M_n(F)$ is a bijective linear map that maps $\operatorname{GL}_n(F)$ to $\operatorname{GL}_n(F)$, then $f^{-1}$ satisfies the conditions of the above theorem. Hence $f$ is of the form $X \mapsto UXV$ or $X \mapsto UX^TV$ for some $U, V \in \operatorname{GL}_n(F)$.

Assuming that $F$ is an algebraically closed field, by Theorem 2 in [2] if $f: M_n(F) \rightarrow M_n(F)$ is a linear map that preserves $\operatorname{GL}_n(F)$, it is nonsingular. Thus it is of the form $X \mapsto UXV$ or $X \mapsto UX^TV$ for some $U, V \in \operatorname{GL}_n(F)$.

If $F$ is not algebraically closed, the claim is false, and you can construct counterexamples using Theorem 3 in [2]. Consider for example the map $f: M_2(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow M_2(\mathbb{R})$ defined by $$\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix} \mapsto \begin{pmatrix} a & c \\ -c & a \end{pmatrix}$$

You can check that $f$ preserves $\operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbb{R})$, but $f$ is not invertible as a linear map.

---

**EDIT:** There is also a bit more to be said. The main result of [3] you gives a classification of linear maps $f: M_n(F) \rightarrow M_n(F)$ such that $f(\operatorname{GL}_n(F)) \subseteq \operatorname{GL}_n(F)$.

In particular, Theorem 2 in [3] implies that if there exists a singular map $f: M_n(F) \rightarrow M_n(F)$ such that $f(\operatorname{GL}_n(F)) \subseteq \operatorname{GL}_n(F)$, then there exists an $n$-dimensional subspace $V$ of $M_n(F)$ such that $V \setminus \{0\} \subset \operatorname{GL}_n(F)$. The existence of such a subspace (called a full non-singular subspace) implies the existence of a $n$-dimensional division algebra over $F$. In the case of $F = \mathbb{R}$, the famous Bott-Milnor-Kervaire result implies that $n$-dimensional division algebras can only exist for $n = 1$, $n = 2$, $n = 4$, and $n = 8$. Hence we conclude the following.

> Let $f: M_n(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow M_n(\mathbb{R})$ be a linear map such that $f(\operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb{R})) \subseteq f(\operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb{R}))$. If $n \not\in \{2,4,8\}$, then $f$ is bijective and there exist $U, V \in \operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb{R})$ such that either $f(X) = UXV$ for all $X \in M_n(\mathbb{R})$, or $f(X) = UX^TV$ for all $X \in M_n(\mathbb{R})$.

Note that the example $f: M_2(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow M_2(\mathbb{R})$ above corresponds to the division algebra $\mathbb{C}$, which is isomorphic to $$\left\{ \begin{pmatrix} a & c \\ -c & a \end{pmatrix} : a,c \in \mathbb{R} \right\}.$$

Using quaternions you can construct an example for $n = 4$, and with octonions for $n = 8$.

---

[1] Dieudonné, Jean. *Sur une généralisation du groupe orthogonal à quatre variables.* Arch. Math. **1** (1949), 282–287.

[2] Botta, Peter. *Linear maps that preserve singular and nonsingular matrices.* Linear Algebra Appl. **20** (1978), no. 1, 45–49.

[3] de Seguins Pazzis, Clément. *The singular linear preservers of non-singular matrices.* Linear Algebra Appl. **433** (2010), no. 2, 483–490.

Comment: Great answer (+1). I was trying to see whether or not $n=2$ is again exceptional. But it seems not.

Comment: Thank you for this very interesting and complete answer! Do you know what happens if I assume in addition that the restriction of my linear map $M_n(\mathbb R) \to M_n(\mathbb R)$ to $\text{GL}_n(\mathbb R)$ is a bijection $\text{GL}_n(\mathbb R) \to \text{GL}_n(\mathbb R)$? (So this rules out your counter example in $n=2$). The answer for that does not seem to follow immediately from the results you have cited. (I looked at the paper [2]). Thanks again for your time and effort, really.

Comment: Actually, on further thought, I think it does follow, since we can prove that our map $T$ is non-singular, Indeed, $\text{Image}(T) \supseteq \text{GL}_n(\mathbb R)$ and is also closed-hence it contains all singular matrices as well. Thus, $T:M_n(\mathbb R) \to M_n(\mathbb R)$ is surjective, hence also injective. This implies that $T(\{\det =0\})=\{\det =0\}$ so Dieudonné's theorem applies.

Comment: Last question: Do you have an idea for what happens if we only require $T(\text{GL}_n^+(\mathbb R) ) =  \text{GL}_n^+(\mathbb R))$, i.e. $T$ maps bijectively the matrices of positive determinant onto themselves.

Comment: Actually, I now see that this again would imply that $T$ is non-singular, but it is not immediately clear to me if it would necessarily preserve the entire $\text{GL}_n$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde: Indeed there are examples for $n = 4$ and $n = 8$ as well, but these are the only ones. It turns out that the exceptions correspond to the existence of real division algebras.

Comment: @AsafShachar: Regarding your second comment, it is clear that $\operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb{R})$ generates $M_n(\mathbb{R})$ as a vector space, so $T$ would be bijective in this case. I am not sure what happens when you look at maps preserving positive determinants. You might want to search in the literature for papers on "linear preservers" or "linear preserver problems" for more.